# C# Prism how to change the default DialogResult passed when closing a dialog window

Tags: c#, prism

I have created a _dialogService and I am showing a dialog in prism.

I am handling all the button presses in the ViewModel. I have handeled the Esc key.

But I can not find a way to handle the Close window button [X].

Yes it calls the `CanCloseDialog` method but I would need to pass a `DialogResult` there but cant find a solution to do that. On default it passes `DialogResult.None` but I would need it to change depending on circumstances.

What is the best or any approach to change the default DialogResult passed when closing the window using the [X] button?

Comment: Maybe that's something default in the existing assembly and you can't change. I highly recommand adding another button (X) and try to manipulate the actions right there and handle your event saving the result you are looking for

Comment: What's wrong with the dialog service provided by prism?